# Calculate AD password age from expiration date Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to calculate the age of the password, in days, using the PasswordLastSet property. I've created the below code but Password Age never outputs anything. I'm guessing there is a type error but I'm not sure how to convert to DateTime. Any thoughts?

```
Get-ADComputer myComputer -Properties PasswordLastSet | Select-Object -Property PasswordLastSet, @{Name = 'Password Age';Expression = {Get-Date - ([datetime]($_.PasswordLastSet))}}
```

Comment: does `PasswordLastSet` in your `Select-Object` have anything in it?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey No it only has a date, for example: 11/30/2018 12:00:00 PM

Comment: so it DOES have a value [*grin*] ... my local account has that field blank, and you aint testing for that. [*grin*] ///// this works for me - `((Get-Date) - [datetime]'11/30/2018 12:00:00 PM').Days`. i THINK your problem is that your `Get-Date` is not enclosed in parens. try it ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes! That was the problem. I don't understand why the parens are needed around Get-Date

Comment: Without the parentheses PowerShell thinks that `- ([datetime]($_.PasswordLastSet))` is a parameter for `Get-Date`.

Comment: Also, you don't need the cast since `$_.PasswordLastSet` is already a `DateTime`.

Comment: @Cole - as `Gabriel Luci` pointed out, without the parens around it, `Get-Date` will try to use the remainder of the line as input. [*grin*]

Comment: I understand, because of the "-". Thank you!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you should post that (the missing parens thing) as an answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - done! [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the failure is the lack of parens around the `Get-Date` call. Without those parens, the cmdlet tries to use the remainder of the line as input ... [*grin*] wrapping the cmdlet in parens - `(Get-Date)` - forces the cmdlet to run *without* trying to parse the remainder of the line.